# App crashes after adding Interstitial ad

Tags: android, firebase, admob, interstitial

The banner ad is working fine, and than I tried to add the Interstitial ad but now my app crashes.

This is the Logcat:

```
03-02 16:37:32.523 1867-1867/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-02 16:37:32.614 1867-1867/com.aaron.waller.angelasoundboard W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.aaron.waller.angelasoundboard-2/lib/arm64
03-02 16:37:32.631 1867-1867/com.aaron.waller.angelasoundboard I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
03-02 16:37:32.878 1867-1867/com.aaron.waller.angelasoundboard E/Bundle: unparcel readArrayMapInternal exception
03-02 16:37:32.880 1867-1867/com.aaron.waller.angelasoundboard W/Ads: Could not get info for ad overlay.
```

My build.gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.1.8'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What does the Logcat content mean and how can I solve it?
Did I miss something?
Here are the codes I addet for the Interstitial ad:

In my MainActivity.java:

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
```

In my MainActivity.java onCreate:

```
 // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });
```

And this is my string.xml:

```
<string name="admob_interstitial_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>
```

This is the example id and not my own.

Comment: Try using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

Comment: Is there a proper stack trace for the exception in LogCat? The LogCat you posted isn't super helpful